# How to get an Arrow shape on the below provided JS filddle circular progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m trying to get an Arrow shape for the below code of circular progress bar. But it seems impossible for me so far, hence my limited experience in CSS and styling.

Please help or guide me how do I get an Arrow shape at the end of the circular progress bar.

The present circular progress bar looks like this:

[image]

How I want it..

[image]

Please find the given JSfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/jh1s7raq/

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:after, :before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.progress{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: relative;
}
.progress:after{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 12px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.progress > span{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.progress .progress-left{
    left: 0;
}
.progress .progress-bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
    border-width: 12px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.progress .progress-left .progress-bar{
    left: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 80px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
    border-left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
    transform-origin: center left;
}
.progress .progress-right{
    right: 0;
}
.progress .progress-right .progress-bar{
    left: -100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 80px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
    border-right: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
    transform-origin: center right;
    animation: loading-1 1.8s linear forwards;
}
.progress .progress-value{
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #012C52;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
.progress.blue .progress-bar{
    border-color: #012C52;
}
.progress.blue .progress-left .progress-bar{
    animation: loading-2 1.5s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
.progress.yellow .progress-bar{
    border-color: #fdba04;
}
.progress.yellow .progress-left .progress-bar{
    animation: loading-3 1s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
.progress.pink .progress-bar{
    border-color: #ed687c;
}
.progress.pink .progress-left .progress-bar{
    animation: loading-4 0.4s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
.progress.green .progress-bar{
    border-color: #1abc9c;
}
.progress.green .progress-left .progress-bar{
    animation: loading-5 1.2s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
@keyframes loading-1{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-2{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
        transform: rotate(144deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-3{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-4{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
        transform: rotate(36deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-5{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
        transform: rotate(126deg);
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px){
    .progress{ margin-bottom: 20px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="progress blue" style="margin-top:50px;">
                <span class="progress-left">
                    <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                </span>
                <span class="progress-right">
                    <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                </span>
                <div class="progress-value">90%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I m not clear on my question... Thanks

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError please check the update in the question, Have uploaded the jsfiddle link

Comment: Looks as though Bhuwan already has an answer for you. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add markup in your html for arrow element like

```
<span class="arrow"></span>
```

And then add css for it

```
.progress>span.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  animation: rotate 3.3s linear forwards;
}

.progress>span.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  border-width: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: -8px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(324deg)
  }
}
```

Check working example below. let me know if you have any doubts on it

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:after,
:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.progress {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: none;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 12px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.progress>span:not(.arrow) {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress>span.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  animation: rotate 3.3s linear forwards;
}

.progress>span.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  border-width: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: -8px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(324deg)
  }
}

.progress .progress-left {
  left: 0;
}

.progress .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  border-width: 12px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.progress .progress-left .progress-bar {
  left: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
  border-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.progress .progress-right {
  right: 0;
}

.progress .progress-right .progress-bar {
  left: -100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
  border-right: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
  transform-origin: center right;
  animation: loading-1 1.8s linear forwards;
}

.progress .progress-value {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #012C52;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}

.progress.blue .progress-bar {
  border-color: #012C52;
}

.progress.blue .progress-left .progress-bar {
  animation: loading-2 1.5s linear forwards 1.8s;
}

.progress.yellow .progress-bar {
  border-color: #fdba04;
}

.progress.yellow .progress-left .progress-bar {
  animation: loading-3 1s linear forwards 1.8s;
}

.progress.pink .progress-bar {
  border-color: #ed687c;
}

.progress.pink .progress-left .progress-bar {
  animation: loading-4 0.4s linear forwards 1.8s;
}

.progress.green .progress-bar {
  border-color: #1abc9c;
}

.progress.green .progress-left .progress-bar {
  animation: loading-5 1.2s linear forwards 1.8s;
}

@keyframes loading-1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
    transform: rotate(144deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
    transform: rotate(36deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-5 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
    transform: rotate(126deg);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .progress {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="progress blue" style="margin:50px;">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <span class="progress-left">
          <span class="progress-bar"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="progress-right">
          <span class="progress-bar"></span>
        </span>
        <div class="progress-value">90%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle link:** https://jsfiddle.net/jh1s7raq/1/